# Smart TV App SDKs and support of auto start and auto update

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, lg, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I'm a newbe in SmartTV app development and trying to figure out if the related devices (SmartTVs) through their SDKs of the two major vendors Samsung and LG support the following when it comes to a custom implemented app:

1. Is it possible to auto start the app on TV start/restart? and if yes
   how? Does someone know any reference in their APIs of how it is done?
2. if there is a newer version of my app how does the updates takes
   place? Is it possible to automatically update the app or at least
   send some short of notification for software update needed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no way to achieve autostart in SDK distributed by vendors.
   But there is at least one app, that starts with TV (Some European
   IPTV provider, can't remember name). You need to contact with
   vendors support and find out for yourself.
2. Samsung apps distributed
   and updated through its store, you upload updated version on seller
   portal and its distributed on tv. Users are prompted to update app
   when new version is available.

   LG hosted apps you can update yourself, packaged apps - same as with Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

I add some notes:

1. auto start is possible in some countries on Samsung as ticker app. This ticker app is available only in some countries (I think in Korea and U.S., but I am not sure). If you want ticker app you can switch samsung to the "hotel mode" in the samsung service menu.
2. auto update is available when you set the flag in config.xml 
   `<autoUpdate itemtype="boolean">y</autoUpdate>`

Comment: I have a european TV and need to autostart and application but ticker app is aparently not available in european models. If I switch to Hotel mode, will the ticker functionality be available then?